# Abstract Class Variable Python

Tags: python

How can I state that an abstract class variable must be defined with `abcmeta`.

e.g.

```
class AbstractMover(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    _destination_folder = NotImplementedError # how do I do something like this

    @property
    def destination_folder(self):
        return self._destination_folder
```

and when it's inherited, it should raise an error if the `_destination_folder` is not specified.

```
class ConcreteMover(AbstractMover): pass # should error

class ConcreteMover(AbstractMover):
    _destination_folder = "path/to/folder" # works fine
```

This should then let me do

```
>>> ConcreteMover().destination_folder
path/to/folder
```

BUT It should raise an error if `_destination_folder` is not defined in the concrete class.

Comment: In this case, *just use `@abstractmethod` / `@property` / `def _destination_folder(self): pass`*. The actual implementation doesn't have to use a method or property object, the only requirement that is tested for is that the name exists.

Comment: @MartijnPieters thanks, I'm just trying to get `mypy` & pylint off my back, it doesn't like that it's being passed a callable.

Comment: Are you using Python 3.6 or newer? Then make `_destination_folder` a [variable annotation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/) without a value set.

Comment: @MartijnPieters how would that look, I currently have `@abstractmethod def _destination_folder(self) -> str: pass` and get the mypy error: `Incompatible return value type (got "Callable[[], str]", expected "str")`

Comment: you forgot the `@property`, you need *both*.

Comment: ah, that makes more sense, thanks! Works perfectly now, many thanks for your help.

Comment: @MartijnPieters What is the purpose of the `@property` decorator? Couldn't it simply be omitted without cancelling the _abstractness_? Where did that idea come from?

Comment: @303: sure you can, but then you defined a method, not an attribute. Other tools that look at the ABC, like a language server for an IDE like Visual Studio Code then tell the developer to use a call instead of referencing the attribute.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ah, that seems to make a lot of sense. The only problem with using the `@property` decorator is that you can't provide a default value that the derived class can use. While not all too common, such a [scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39388910/7107236) is still viable. What would be the most suitable workaround? Add a `@staticmethod` decorator instead? Or use a custom `@classproperty` like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3203659/7107236)?

Comment: @303: just have the property return the default value!

Comment: I think it should be `@property` / `@abstractmethod` / `def _destination_folder(self):`. The order matters. (https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/60471)