# Is there any use case for a pure virtual final method in C++?

Tags: c++, final

```cpp
class C
{
    public:
    virtual void f() final = 0;
};
```

[Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/z9TWdqsfq)

To me this looks like a programming mistake. `=0` says it has no implementation yet and must be overriden, but `final` says that nobody can override it. So it will never have an implementation.

Do I miss something? I wonder that I don't get any warning for above code.

Comment: Is this something you saw in actual code, and are wondering what the real world use case might have been? Or is it something you thought of, and are wondering why the standard doesn't forbid it?

Comment: Of note - clang will warn if the class itself is final.

Comment: @Brian61354270: I came up with this code while learning about `virtual`, `override` and `final` in C++.

Comment: It is legal : see 2) of https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/final. The C++ core guidelines are a bit more clear on the intent [R.128 virtual/final/override](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#c128-virtual-functions-should-specify-exactly-one-of-virtual-override-or-final)

Comment: There could be some obscure use in template metaprogramming, but I can't think of anything off the top of my head.

Comment: Minor point: `=0` doesn't say it has no implementation; it says that derived classes must override the function if the derived type will be used to create an object. Pure virtual functions **can** have implementations. That's sometimes handy to provide default behavior; the derived class can call the base version.

Comment: @PeteBecker: thanks. I modified the question to say "it has no implementation yet and must be overriden"

Comment: @PeteBecker: why should a derived class call f() on the base class, if the base class is implemented as =0? I can't make that work: https://godbolt.org/z/cGTq3ncsM

Comment: @PeteBecker: Did you mean "That's sometimes handy to provide default behavior; the *base* class can call the *derived* version."? I think there are some GoF design patterns making use of that.

Comment: C++ allows for a lot of things that don't make sense.  It just doesn't opt to forbid the nonsensical things, because C++ is not a nanny language.

Comment: @ThomasWeller -- no, the derived version can call the base version. For example, a derived class might call the base version so that the base version does whatever is needed in the base subject, and then continue with the processing needed in the derived class. The base version has to have an implementation, which, if I remember correctly, can only be written inline in the class definition. So `struct base { virtual void f() = 0 { std::cout << "hello from base\n"; } }; struct derived : base { void f() { base::f(); std::cout << "hello from derived\n"; } };` Caution: written but not tested.

Comment: @PeteBecker: that doesn't compile in GCC nor Clang: https://godbolt.org/z/811aoEfEn It seems you can't have `=0` and implementation in `{}` at the same time.

Comment: @ThomasWeller -- as I said, not tested. <g> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39388152/why-does-c-support-pure-virtual-functions-with-an-implementation